# Can't get past the system lock PIN code

Tags: macbook-pro, activation-lock

I locked my MacBook using Find My iPhone and now when attempting to start using it again, I cannot type my PIN into the unlock section. Nothing happens. I can't even click on sleep, restart, shut down or the internet options.

I tried <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>. Both just came up with a different password screen which I put the PIN into and then they went back to the PIN screen. I have no idea what else I can do.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options available.

- You can purchase a EFI Rom chip for your particular model computer, attach it to the logic board and it will bypass the system EFI.  http://www.cmizapper.com/components/chips.html
- You can attempt to rewrite the existing EFI chip  https://ghostlyhaks.com/blog/blog/hacking/18-apple-efi-bypass
- You can attempt to brute force the password with an Arduino Teensy https://github.com/orvtech/efi-bruteforce or similar. http://www.cmizapper.com/products/brutus.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your system has the [firmware password](http://www.cnet.com/news/efi-firmware-protection-locks-down-newer-macs/) set.

You will need to enter the firmware password first, before you can get back into your system and enter the recovery pin.

Answer (score 0):

Try blocking the MAC address (aka, Airport ID) at your router.  Seems that if the MBP can't reach the internet and Apple's servers, the lockout goes to sh!te.  Can't believe it was this easy to get around the "lockout."